# MongoDB writing a correct query

Tags: mongodb

I am new to `MongoDB` and Im trying to write a query to extract data from a collection I created but I am stuck in trying to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to get all the fields except `_id` for all movies that are **NOT** based on things

How could I do this in a MongoDB query? I've read and looked up many things trying to learn about Mongo but so far I haven't gotten anything. Thank you very much in advance.

This is my collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5363738hhhe2282828282w"), "coll" : "PageMaster" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("0000222211223333sssswq2"), "coll" : "Honey1", "Jink" : { "head" : "Jink1"} }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5hjkwwowwj7373365252wwww"), "coll" : "Rodger", "things" : { "head": "Honey"} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the records where the key `BOOK` does `not exist`. Those are the records that we want. And exclude the `_id` field in the projection parameter.

```
 db.MOVI.find({"BOOK":{$exists:false}},{"_id":0})
```

**EDIT**:

For using `printjson` to print the cursor contents:

```
var myCursor = db.MOVI.find({"BOOK":{$exists:false}},{"_id":0});
myCursor.forEach(function(doc)
{
    printjson(doc);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also have one more question about this query, how would I print this query using a printjson() function?

Comment: db.MOVI.find({"BOOK":{$exists:false}},{"_id":0}).forEach(function(doc){printjson(doc)}), should work. But on the console you do not require to print it explicitly.

Comment: where are you getting (doc) from? Is that suppose to be the name of my collection?

Comment: No. `doc` is a formal `parameter name` to the function. the find() method returns a cursor, and basically we iterate the cursor using a forEach loop. TFor each record in the resultset, we execute a function, in which we print the record.

Comment: When i run the printjson query, I just get the dots (...) and nothing else. What did I do wrong? I entered the query exactly as you said.

Comment: What version of MongoDb are you using?

Comment: mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.5

Comment: I want to print the query using printjson()

Comment: Why do you want to print the query? See my updated edit for printing the result. printjson is a function used to print an object in its JSON notation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Sorry for being a little noobish its just my first time using Mongo and theres still so much for me to learn about it.

Comment: No problem. My pleasure to help:)